Does geopandas overlay use spatial indexing
I have a general question about geopandas overlay method. I want to know whether it already uses spatial indexing or not.
If not, how would I apply indexing?
Background I do an intersection with parcels in a German state with land usage and InVeKos and believe me there are many tiny parcels. My current solution, is to encapsulate it in a function and only load the data villagewise (use bbox parameter of read_file with a buffered village shape) and do an intersection per village and run that on several cores at once. The progress bar states it will take days.

As BERA already stated, geopandas overlays use a spatial index out of the box. If performance would still be suboptimal, you could try geofileops.intersection which uses a spatial index as well as parallel processing. Disclaimer: I'm the developer of geofileops.

Pieter and @BERA thanks for your help. It was not really clear to me from the documentation alone and LLMs ChatGPT 3.5, BING, PERPLEXITY more or less say the opposite. I am still wondering why it is so slow and will ask it in a separate Question.

Yes, see the comment of Joris to this question: Overlay Union Geopandas improve performance:

@klewis use_sindex is deprecated in the 0.4 version of geopandas, as
the new implementation of overlay always uses a spatial index. –
joris Nov 29, 2018 at 23:12

He is one of the core developers of GeoPandas
